# lens lineup question -- focusing to DSLR

Tags: discussion

I'm planning to edit the very popular [How much do lens lineups vary across DSLR platforms?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-platforms) question to specifically mentionDSLRs, and then ask a [separate one for mirrorless compact system cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33743/how-much-do-lens-lineups-vary-across-mirrorless-camera-systems).

It happens that (due to the age of the question) most of the questions *mostly* refer to SLR systems anyway. In fact, that's arguably the intent of the question.

I think it will be more useful to do this and to have a separate one for the newer type of camera, but I wanted to mention it here before I went and did it. Anyone object?

Comment: No objections here...

Comment: looks like the new question on mirrorless is off to a great start. nice work @mattdm

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue here when considering formats like the EOS-M from cannon where only a handfull of lenses have been created however all canon lenses can work on EOS-M bodies with the appropriate adapter supplied by canon.
Just a thought

Comment: I doubt there's any issue. Lenses connected through adapters don't count. For NEX you also can connect any A-mount lens created since 1987 and it'll work with DSLR-quality AF (unlike with EOS adapter) thanks to SLT and DSLR AF system in adapter itself. But it doesn't matter. It's not a system lens. Same with EOS-M: It can use EOS lenses through adapters, but they are from the different system, so hardly can be discussed.

Comment: Or, from an alternate point of view: talking about which lenses are _easily adapted_ for each system is a worthwhile point for the answers. Either way, I agree it's not really a problem.